# Merge multiple exact query results in Sphinx Search

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I need to search multiple exact keyword matches in Sphinx Search (PHP). For instance, I have the keywords (note that these are queried all at once):

"facebook user"
"google plus member"
"myspace fan"

The results should be able to return exact matches for each keyword above all combined in one result.

An example of the results I want it to show is:

1. how to unfriend a facebook user
2. myspace fan gets shot
3. happy myspace fan posts a video on youtube
4. unhappy google plus member
5. facebook user who claims to be a cop
6. funny google plus member

Notice that each result above have exact matches with any of the 3 keywords used. Somehow when I tried it in Sphinx, it doesn't work. Here's my code in PHP:

```
$sphinx->setMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 );
$sphinx->query( '"facebook user" "google plus member" "myspace fan"' );
```

What I did is to add quotes to each keyword to denote that I'm searching for exact matches, and just simply separated each keyword by spaces. Apparently, this doesn't work, so I need a good way to solve this.

Please help me with this, I'm not yet very familiar with Sphinx Search though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Extended query syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax). In your case you need | (OR) operator between phrases.